# Powershell foreach results to array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the below code and get the results to an HTML email.  If I just run it as is, all of the output is on one line, which is a mess.  I thought I could save the foreach right to an array, but that's not working. . .  Just getting a blank array.  If I run it without, I get output to the screen, so I know I'm getting results.

```
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential

$customers = Get-MsolPartnerContract -All
$body = @(foreach ($customer in $customers) {

  if ($customer.defaultdomainname -notlike "*Domain1*" -and $customer.defaultdomainname -notlike "*DomainABC*") {
    Get-MsolUser -All -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly -TenantId $($customer.TenantId) | ? {$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -eq $null -and $_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE"}  | select UserPrincipalName
  }
})
```

Comment: Capturing `foreach` output like this works. How do you output `$body`? I guess there's where the error lies.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to get the UPNs of all Azure AD enabled users with License and without Strong Auth that are not on Domain1 or DomainABC domain/tenant. Is that right?

Comment: What do you do with `$body` afterwards? How are you composing the html?

Comment: Really, just for testing, all I've done so far is a $body to see some results on the screen.  Nothing.  Tried $body[1] - nothing.

Comment: What is $body after doing this?  Is it an array?  If so, an array of what?

Comment: $body should be an array since the foreach has @() around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an instance to play/validate with, but try it this way (use whatever code or other formatting you choose of course):

```
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$body = @()

(Get-MsolPartnerContract -All) | 
ForEach-Object {

  if ($PSItem.defaultdomainname -notlike '*Domain1*' -and 
      $PSItem.defaultdomainname -notlike '*DomainABC*'
  ) 
  {
    $body.Add(
                (
                    Get-MsolUser -All -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly -TenantId $($PSItem.TenantId) | 
                    Where-Object {
                        $PSItem.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -eq $null -and 
                        $PSItem.isLicensed -eq 'TRUE'
                    }
                ).UserPrincipalName
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought += with an array was frowned upon as it creates a new array every time?

Comment: Yeppers it is, but you still see it used in tons of code, see in the PowerShell repo, and I already updated with the other option. So, choices, choices...

Comment: @Pat If you only add a few elements to an array it doesn't make a relevant difference. Still I prefer to avoid `+=` which often results in cleaner code.

Comment: No worries, glad, it helped. Happy scripting and stay safe out there.